# Presto: Explain plan not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, emr, presto

I am facing issues getting explain plan/analyze while running presto queries. When i try to run an "explain" command in Presto, it errors out saying "Index Out Of Bounds" -

```
explain select * from <table>;
Query 20170605_193620_00057 failed: index (1) must be less than size (1)
```

Not sure what i am doing wrong here. It works if the query is really simple, like "Select 1", but not for others. Any ideas?

Comment: https://github.com/prestodb/presto/issues/7672 ?